# List of prime numbers - unexpected output

Tags: python, python-3.x, primes

output: `<generator object <genexpr> at 0x00000293AA2F8E60>` instead of the list of prime numbers that I was attempting to obtain.

```
import math
#here i try to use trial division to validate whether a number is false or not     
def isPrime(n):
    d = {}
    u = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    i = 2
    while (i <= u):
        if (n % i == 0):
            return False
        i +=1
        return True
#here I attempt to find all the prime numbers between 1 and 5000
print(isPrime(n) for n in range(1,5000))
```

Comment: what happens if you instead have `print(list(isPrime(n) for n in range(1,5000)))`?

Comment: Is this python code? Perhaps you should add an appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 1):

You built a generator, and then told Python to print that *object*.  That's what you got.  From your description, I think that you want a list comprehension that will give you a list of primes.

Try this:

```
print ( [n for n in range(1, 5000) if isPrime(n) ] )
```

Note that you want to print the prime number, *not* the return value from **isPrime**.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is this:

```
import math
def isPrime(n):
    u = math.floor(math.sqrt(n))
    i = 2
    while (i <= u):
        if (n % i == 0):
            return False
        i +=1
    return True

for n in range(1, 5000):
    print(isPrime(n))
```